# Ruby: URI concatenate behavior

Tags: ruby, uri

I am currently developing an HTML parser and I came to one specific website that is not properly coded in terms of urls. On the main page ("http://example.com/a/b"), I have some links starting with "a/b" without the initial "/". Ruby URI works correctly as per my understanding of relative paths:

```
uri = URI("http://example.com/a/b")
(uri + "a/b").to_s
==> http://example.com/a/a/b
```

However, the behavior seems to be different in a browser such as Firefox or Chrome, as the page is directed to http://example.com/a/b (which works by the way).

Have you seen this before and what would you suggest to have the same behavior in Ruby than in Web browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I think uri + 'a/b' is simply doing a string concatenation.

What I would suggest is to try this:

```
File.join('http://www.example.com', 'a/b')
```

File.join supports this kind of operation :)

Comment: the URI "+" is doing more than string concatenation, as it joins an URI with another absolute or relative URI taking into account the initial one. It does a great job I think, but I don't understand my browsers behavior.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that.. As for the browser behavior.. weird but correct. Stuff that's not prefixed with a / is relative to the current URL. so if you are on example.com/a a link to a/b will net example.com/a/a/b

Comment: Exactly, I assume that browsers have some kind of fallback modes for not properly coded websites.